in OOP Is it correct to pass an attribute to the method as a parameter?
I wrote a recursive program to print the values of a binary search tree from the smallest to the largest (in order) and it can be written in two ways:

This can be written in such a way that the function receives the root as a parameter as follows:
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


class BinarySearchTree:
    root = None



    def in_order(self, root):
        current = root
        if current is None:
            return
        self.in_order(current.left)
        print(current.data)
        self.in_order(current.right)



t1.in_order(t1.root)

The problem in this way is that the user has to give direct access to the root (t1.root)

This can be written in such a way that the user does not have to give the root as a parameter, but we will have to write it as two functions:
    def in_order2(self):
        self.inner_inorder(self.root)

    def inner_inorder(self, current)
        if current is None:
            return
        self.in_order(current.left)
        print(current.data)
        self.in_order(current.right)


t1.in_order2()



Which form of writing is considered more correct?

Why not just access self.root in in_order?

In my understanding, this is not a good way to pass as an attribute argument of an object, but correct me if I'm wrong

You wouldn't be passing anything in that case. self.root can be accessed from inside the function.

You aren't defining BinarySearchTree correctly in the first place. root should be an instance attribute, not a class attribute, in which case root is accessible (indirectly) as an argument to in_order, being an attribute of the parameter self.

How about something like this:
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


class BinarySearchTree:
    root = None


    def in_order(self, current=None, depth=0):
        if depth == 0 and current is None:
            current = self.root
        if current is None:
            return
        self.in_order(current.left, depth+1)
        print(f"{' '* depth}{current.data}")
        self.in_order(current.right, depth+1)


t1 = BinarySearchTree()
t1.root = TreeNode(1)
t1.root.left = TreeNode(2)
t1.root.right = TreeNode(3)
t1.root.right.left = TreeNode(4)
t1.in_order()

This uses default parameters, a very nice feature of python, to make the current and depth parameters in the in_order call optional.
The depth parameter is required to make sure we don’t fall into a recursive loop, by always going back to the root node in the case that current is None. It also has the nice benefit of enabling you to do something with that information, as I did in the print statement to make the output more interesting : )

You don't need the root property, just send a TreeNode instance
class BinarySearchTree:
    def in_order(self, root):
        current = root
        if current is None:
            return
        self.in_order(current.left)
        print(current.data)
        self.in_order(current.right)

node1 = TreeNode(1)
node2 = TreeNode(2)
node3 = TreeNode(3)
node4 = TreeNode(4)

node1.right = node2
node2.left = node3
node2.right = node4

tree = BinarySearchTree()

tree.in_order(node1)
# Output:
# 1
# 3
# 2
# 4

tree.in_order(node2)
# Output:
# 3
# 2
# 4


And to OP: there is no need for the class or object at all; it's a plain dfs function that searches through a tree structure. If it's not going to keep any state, it's not necessary to wrap it in a class. I'd also drop the root/current nomenclature and just use root - the point of using a recursive function to explore a binary tree is that every node can be considered the root of that branch of the tree.

I would suggest making each node a search tree itself so that the in_order method has access to the root node of each subtree as self at each recursion level:
class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def in_order(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.in_order()
        print(self.data)
        if self.right:
            self.right.in_order()

so that:
t1 = BinarySearchTree(1)
t2 = BinarySearchTree(2)
t3 = BinarySearchTree(3)
t1.left = t2
t1.right = t3
t1.in_order()

outputs:
2
1
3


System Design vs Object-Oriented Design

In OOP, is it correct to pass an attribute to the method as a parameter? 
[ ... ] 
Which form of writing is considered more correct?

There's no objective* answer to this. Object-Oriented programming is a paradigm that allows you to structure your code as conceptual/abstract artefacts in the form of class definitions saying that the aforementioned artefacts (i.e. objects) belonging to a given class share
structure defined by properties they all have, with the
properties being themselves objects of some specified
class (Chambers, 2014, p. 169).
What this means is that OOP grants you an heuristic for laying out your code (i.e. how objects are presented and accessed (Savinov, 2014)) provided you've made certain formal or standard design choices. OOP does not exactly tell you "artefact x can/cannot be parsed to artefact y" without having specified access levels for the corresponding operation prior, which in turn prescribes what can be done (parsed) or not in a given situation.
Furthermore, OOP tells you "here's a paradigm for laying out the structure of your code". Whether to parse some attribute x to some object y is a system design/constraint/requirement issue.
This implies that, you can write 100% OOP style code and still go ahead and break "rules" anyways (especially if the language does not enforce specific OOP dichotomies, which is a flexibility Python is known to have).
*Pun unintended.

So how well can we write a "OOP-compliant" implementation of your program?
As mentioned earlier, OOP is simply an heuristic-paradigm, not a set of programming mandates or "rules", so what we can otherwise aim for is applying the concepts of Object-Oriented (Analysis and) Design (OOD/OOAD), because your system constraint(s) and use-case(s) are the specifiers of what attributes to parse around, and/or how to do so.
I will loosely adopt the Microprocess Design & Analysis technique used by Booch et. al (2007) in Chapter 6 (p. 273), and strongly follow the model-driven (UML) OOAD approach used by Dennis, Wixom & Tegarden (2015). As a result, we'll breakdown the design into the following components:

Conceptual Model (Language-independent system overview, e.g. Requirements, System Constraints)
Functional Model (What the system does, e.g. Activity Diagram, Use-Case Diagram)
Structural Model (Abstract layout and relationship of system artefacts, e.g. Class Diagram)
Behavioral Model (How the system (or specific feature) works, e.g. State Diagram)
Implementation (Programmatic translation of design, e.g. Actual Working Code, Compiled Program)


System Constraints for Binary Search Tree
To specify my own design constraints, I'll be adapting the BST layout used by Goodrich et. al (2013) in Chapter 11.

A Tree object is by default public; its underlying class (also public) encapsulates internal private access to the specifications and instantiation of a privately nested _Node class.

A private _Node class cannot be instantiated independently of a public Tree object (i.e. composition design pattern) in order to prevent illegal manipulation of the Tree structure. However, an instance of the _Node class can be provided by the Tree object with public read-only getter methods.

The private _root property of a Tree object must NOT be publicly mutated; instead, we provide a getter method using the @property decorator syntax for read-only public access. Publicly mutating the _root can lead to unexpected loss of data contained within the instantiated Tree.


Functional Model for Binary Search Tree (Context: Inorder Traversal)
Since the default parameter feature of Python is not universal across all programming languages, let's opt for a non-recursive inorder traversal design instead, this helps prevent breaking our constraints, and avoid writing two functions (other answers already showed how to still implement it recursively without accessing attributes we would prefer to be inaccessible in such a case).
The following sketch (as opposed to a fully-fledged UML-compliant diagram) is what the activity diagram for the iterative inorder traversal would look like instead:
      +-------------------+
      |      Start        |
      +---------|---------+
                |
                v
      +-------------------+
      | Initialize stack  |
      |   (empty)         |
      +---------|---------+
                |
                v
      +-------------------+
      | Set current to    |
      | root of the tree  |
      +---------|---------+
                |
                v
   +----------------------------+
   | While current is not null  |
   | OR stack is not empty:     |
   +------------|---------------+
                |
                v
+-----------------------------------+
| Is current not null?              |
| (Yes)                  (No)       |
+-----|--------------------|--------+
      |                    |
      v                    v
+--------------------+    +-------------------------+
| Push current node  |    | Pop node from stack     |
| to stack           |    +----------|--------------+
| Move to left child |               |
+---------|----------+               v
          |      +-----------------------------+
          |      | Set current to popped node  |
          |      +-------------|---------------+
          |                    |
          |                    v
          |        +------------------------+
          |        | Visit current node     |
          |        +-------------|----------+
          |                      |
          v                      v
  +-------------------+    +----------------------+
  | Move to right     |    | Loop back to check   |
  | child of current  |    | condition            |
  +---------|---------+    +----------------------+
            |
            v
   +----------------+
   | End traversal  |
   +----------------+


Structural Model (Context: Design Pattern & Access Levels)
Just as we've discussed, a sketch of a class diagram representing the composition relationship between the _Node class and the BST class:
+----------------------+
|         BST          |
+----------------------+
| - _root: _Node       |
+----------------------+
| + getRoot()          |
| - _setRoot(_Node)    |
| + insert(value)      |
| + delete(value)      |
| + search(value)      |
| + inorderTraversal() |
+----------------------+
            ♦
            |
            |
            |
+----------------------+
|        _Node         |
+----------------------+
| - value: int         |
| - left: _Node        |
| - right: _Node       |
+----------------------+
| + getValue()         |
| - _setValue(int)     |
| + getLeft()          |
| - _setLeft(_Node)    |
| + getRight()         |
| - _setRight(_Node)   |
+----------------------+


Behavioral Model
This is quite trivial as the subsequent implementation pretty much tells you what you need to know about the states of the program.
Implementation (Context: BST Class and _Node Class)
Translating our models and constraints into code...
class BST:
    class _Node:
        def __init__(self, v):
            self.value = v
            self.left = None
            self.right = None

    def __init__(self):
        self._root = None

    def getRoot(self):
        return self._root

    def _setRoot(self, node):
        self._root = node

    def insert(self, v):
        if not self._root:
            self._setRoot(self._Node(v))
        else:
            current = self._root
            while True:
                if v < current.value:
                    if current.left:
                        current = current.left
                    else:
                        current.left = self._Node(v)
                        break
                elif v > current.value:
                    if current.right:
                        current = current.right
                    else:
                        current.right = self._Node(v)
                        break
                else:
                    break

    def delete(self, v):
        # Implementation of delete method is omitted for brevity
        pass

    def search(self, v):
        # Implementation of search method is omitted for brevity
        pass

    def inorderTraversal(self):
        if not self._root:
            return []

        result = []
        stack = []
        current = self._root

        while True:
            while current:
                stack.append(current)
                current = current.left

            if not stack:
                break

            current = stack.pop()
            result.append(current.value)
            current = current.right

        return result

Putting it together in action!
if __name__ == "__main__":
    bst = BST()
    values = [5, 3, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8]
    for value in values:
        bst.insert(value)

    print("Inorder Traversal:", bst.inorderTraversal())  # Output: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Conclusion
As we have seen, OOP is a means to an end: it gives you the gun and tells you how it can be fired, but whether you choose to do so is entirely left to your system design choices.
